# how do i use async task<iactionresult> to record data to a many-to-many table with entity framework

Tags: json, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Models:

```
    public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PersonEducation> PersonEducations { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PersonExperience> PersonExperiences { get; set; }

    }
    public class PersonEducation
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        public int EducationId { get; set; }
        public Education Education { get; set; }
    }
    public class PersonExperience
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        public int ExperienceId { get; set; }
        public Experience Experiences { get; set; }
    }

    public class Education
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PersonEducation> PersonEducations { get; set; }
    }
    public class Experience
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PersonExperience> PersonExperiences { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Data:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "educations": [
        {
            "description": "Loren Ipsun 1"
        },
        {
            "description": "Loren Ipsun 2"
        },
        {
            "description": "Loren Ipsun 3"
        }

    ],
    "experiences": [
        {
            "description": "Loren Ipsun 1"
        },
        {
            "description": "Loren Ipsun 2"
        },
        {
            "description": "Loren Ipsun 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Controller (Draft):

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PersonEducationsController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult??? Post([FromServices] ???)
             
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                
            }
        }

       
       
    }
```

I Need to create an asynchronous post that inserts the "Person" together with an "Experience" and "Education" List.
I'm having trouble understanding some concepts. I'm a beginner in programming and also in English.

OnModelCreating is already defined in my DataContext

is there anything else i could do or research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your Model class and the Json data, I suggest you could create a view model to transfer the JSON data to the API method. Code as below:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Education> educations { get; set; }
    public List<Experience> experiences { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in the API method, using the following code to insert data into DataBase and return value:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Person>> PostPerson(PersonViewModel person)
    {
        Person newPerson = new Person()
        {
            Name = person.name,      
        }; 
        List<PersonEducation> pelist = new List<PersonEducation>();
        foreach (var edu in person.educations)
        {
            pelist.Add(new PersonEducation()
            {
                Person = newPerson,
                Education = new Education() { Description = edu.Description }
            });
        };

        List<PersonExperience> pexlist = new List<PersonExperience>();
        foreach (var edu in person.experiences)
        {
            pexlist.Add(new PersonExperience()
            {
                Person = newPerson,
                Experiences = new Experience() { Description = edu.Description }
            });
        };

        newPerson.PersonEducations = pelist;
        newPerson.PersonExperiences = pexlist; 

        try
        {
            _context.Persons.Add(newPerson);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var message = ex.Message;

        }

        return CreatedAtAction("GetPerson", new { id = newPerson.Id }, newPerson);
    }
```

The Postman test result like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why, but I had to use the [FromServices] attribute by passing the DbContext and a [FromBody] with PersonViewModel, because I wasn't accepting the DbContext's constructor method on my Controller.

Ficou mais ou menos assim:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Person>> PostPerson([FromServices] DataContext context, 
            [FromBody] PersonViewModel person)
```

And also add to Startup.cs:

```
services.AddScoped <DataContext, DataContext> ();
```

Thanks!